# Custom Tag Helper .SetAttribute() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working in a .NET Core application. I have created myself a custom tag helper for the navigation links in a dashboard sidebar. When the page is active, the nav link gets a class of `active` applied to its `<li>`.

Here's the code for the custom tag helper:

```
public class SidebarLink : TagHelper
{
  private const string ActiveClass = "active";

  [HtmlAttributeName("asp-controller")]
  public string Controller { get; set; }

  [HtmlAttributeName("asp-action")]
  public string Action { get; set; }

  public string Icon { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
  [ViewContext]
  public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

  public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
  {
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    var html =
      $@"<li><a href='{Controller}/{Action}'><i class='material-icons'>{Icon}</i><span class='title'>{Name}</span></a></li>";
    output.TagName = "li";
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(html);
    if (string.Equals(controller, Controller) && string.Equals(action, Action))
    {
      output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", ActiveClass);
    }
    await base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
  }
}
```

When I debug, I can see that my if statement is evaluating to true, so `.SetAttribute()` is being called, but for some reason, my `<li>` does not have the `active` CSS class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this missing some detail? or did it just need a bump?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your html string without the `<li>` tags, so it would be the following:

`var html =
      $@"<li><a href='{Controller}/{Action}'><i class='material-icons'>{Icon}</i><span class='title'>{Name}</span></a></li>"`

You are setting the output tags to `<li>` so you should not need to then set the html content to have them.